# Exclude Token Mismatch error

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel version 5.2 and frequently came across with TokenMismatch error.
How can I exclude log of this Token Mismatch error in daily log file.

So I can easily filter out other errors in my log viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and look for `protected $dontReport`. Add this line to that array: `\Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,`. That should work.

Comment: The solution you have give is perfect but I want to do is to
report the my custom exception on screen but not in error log file.

The above solution stops both report and log.